# renaming a subset of contiguous columns in a data.frame/tible based on name-indexing in R

Tags: r, dplyr, rename, names

I want so select a subset of consecutive columns by column name, and rename with a character vector.

example data:

```
data<-data.frame(foo=1:4, bar=10:13, zoo_1=letters[1:4], zoo_2=letters[5:8])

  foo bar zoo_1 zoo_2
1   1  10     a     e
2   2  11     b     f
3   3  12     c     g
4   4  13     d     h
```

colnames to be replaced: 'bar', 'zoo_1', 'zoo_2'

new names:

```
new_names<-c('a', 'b', 'c')
```

I wanted to use some sort of : operator to select, for instance, the columns with the names bar to zoo_2

I found some weird solutions:

```
#1
names(data)[which(names(df)=='bar'):which(names(df)=='zoo_2')]<-new_names
```

and

```
#2
my_rename<-function(x,y,z){
        names(x)[match(y, names(df))]<-z
        names(x)
}
names(data)<-my_rename(data, c('bar', 'zoo_1', 'zoo_2'), c(new_names)
```

Solution #2 is bad because it requires spelling out all names to be replaced.

Solution #1 allows me to select the names in a 'bar':'zoo_2' style, but is quite verbose and may be confusing to others. I am most interested In a substitute for this (which:which) hack.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rename_at`

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
           rename_at(vars(bar:zoo_2), ~ new_names)
names(data)
#[1] "foo" "a"   "b"   "c"
```

However, in dplyr 1.05, `rename_at` has been superseded by `rename_with`:

```
data2<-data %>%
        rename_with(.cols=bar:zoo_2, ~ new_names)

> identical(data, data2)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Awesome. So the vars() function allows me to use select() - like syntax?. What is the role of this ~ operator here? Why not simply calling new_names as an argument (instead of ' ~ new_names') ?.

I still cant get the use of these '.~' , '~' , '.fun' symbols within function calls (other than in formulas)

Comment: @GuedesBF With `rename_at` or `_with`, you may need the `vars` wrapped or specify `.vars =`.  THe `~` is a lamdba function `function(x)` (shortform in tidyverse)

Comment: @GuedesBF The reason it expects a function `.funs`.  The anonymous/lambda can thus be used here